# Visual Studio 2019 install Python3.7 Package, geting TLS/SSL problem

Tags: python, visual-studio

I was trying to install Python3.7 package inside visual studio however I keep getting 
"`pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the SSL module in Python is not available.`" issues, no matter what package.

The OS is windows I also tried to use CMD to pip, it seems package can be successfully installed, but it does not reflect in Visual Studio.  Tried reinstall Python component in Visual Studio but with no luck.

The visual studio does have both 3.6 and 3.7 and I have Anaconda. Install package works with 3.6 in VS but not for 3.7.  I really don't know where else to look for problem, could be some path configuration problem, environment variable problem?

Comment: Any news on this? I have the same problem

Comment: WFM here (win7, py3.7.3 win64 installed for all users, installin into a newly-created venv). Please provide a [mcve] how to reproduce from a clean state -- how you installed Python (vanilla/anaconda, which settings/packages), VS (e.g. for all users or not, which components), which Python environment you choose/create, how you re are installing packages for it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar symptoms and was able to find a suitable workaround.

**Background:**
Fresh install of Visual Studio 2019 in May 2019, no previous install of anaconda, etc. I could add pypi packages in 3.6 conda environments, but not 3.7. Attempts to install from both VS2019 and powershell would result in the ssl module error you describe.

**Workaround:** I was able to work around this by running `pip install` from the conda command prompt. 
To do this, I navigated to the conda folder, which for me was at: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Miniconda\Miniconda3-x64\Scripts`.
I could run conda.exe but it errors out saying the environment isn't set up. If you modify your path to include the above directory plus several other parent and subs (miniconda3-x64 root, library, library/bin; condabin; maybe others) the error message will actually give you helpful instructions to run `conda init cmd.exe` or something similar to prepare your environment. You can run this for powershell as well. I ran this as admin. Close your shell and reopen, and then you can run `conda activate <environment>`. Once in the conda shell, I could run `pip install <package>` and it all worked fine, and was reflected in VS2019 view immediately.

**TL;DR:** Navigate to the folder where conda.exe lives; run `conda init cmd.exe` as admin; reopen cmd.exe; run `conda activate <environment name>`; run `pip install <package name>`; run `conda deactivate`; return to VS2019, verify, rejoice.